# Unregistering device for notifications delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, push

Just a quick question, isn't there any method in UIApplicationDelegate protocol that confirms that the device is successfully unregistered for remote notifications?

I know the following delegate method that confirms the successful registration of device but was wondering about its counterpart:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

Thanks,
Obaid

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. 
There only is `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` for failing to register remote notifications.

You cannot unregister remote notifications programmatically, because it makes no sense to do so. Registering doesn't mean you actually get notifications.

A user himself has to turn off notifications for specific apps in the settings app under "notification center".

So don't be confused. It just isn't needed. If it was needed, Apple would have done so...

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that you can't unregister from remote notifications from within your app. I think that the dialog asking if you agree to receive push notifications appears the first time you try to register, and after that you control registration from the Settings app.

You can check if push notifications are currently enabled from within the app though by checking the value returned by

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]
```

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];